# Error creating JVM using maven

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I get an error message `Could not create the Java virtual machine` when I do `mvn clean install`.  What should I do now? Should I change anything in `pom.xml`? My java version-1.6 and maven version-3.0.2, all set in `pom.xml`

Errors are::

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on
 project accelerator-common: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
Could not create the Java virtual machine.


        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation fail
ure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
Could not create the Java virtual machine.


        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompiler
Mojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Do you have the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable defined? What is the output of `mvn --version` ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant pom snippet related to `maven compiler plugin` - assuming it is present?  If not, tell us if you use any `JAVA_OPTS` or `MAVEN_OPTS`.

Comment: <build>
<pluginManagement>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>

Comment: Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530)
Maven home: D:\Deep\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using it from an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans?

If so, you may then:

- Set the JAVA_HOME to point to your JDK.
- Configure the Maven options in your IDE to use your Maven install instead of the bundled one.
- Configure the Java Runtime to use the JDK instead of the JRE.

**Configuring the Maven installation in Eclipse**

- Go to Window > Preferences > Maven > Installation.
- Add your Maven installation. Click `Add` and select your Maven install directory.
- Select it as your Maven installation.

**Configuring the installed JREs option in Eclipse**

- Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.
- Add a Standard VM that points to your JDK home directory.
- No VM arguments. Of course, if you have any you may add them.
- Mark it as your JRE.

By default Eclipse uses an embedded Maven installation from the Maven plugin and sometimes uses the Non-JDK JRE as the default Java Runtime.

So the steps to make it work is to have a JDK installed, set the JAVA_HOME, unpack Maven to a directory and then in Eclipse change the Maven installation and point the JRE to a JDK JRE.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am using eclipse indigo, java-home is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out why it could not create it. A common reason is that an invalid command line option is used. e.g. `M2_OPTS=-Xmx1m` will give you this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the java system properties say -Xmx or -Xms which you specify in mvn clean command. I guess there might be a space between the command and the ram size. i.e you may have specified  **-Xmx 128** rather it should be **-Xmx128**. It is a wild guess though

Comment: can you elaborate this.. i mean why and how to set the jvm for mvn clean install..??

Answer (score 0):

Also match your `JAVA_HOME` env variable with JAVA_HOME\bin in `PATH` env. It should be of same arch type.

I faced this problem. I have 16GB ram, and even after setting `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` it did not work after few maven executions and gave errors.

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```